# Router Disconnects Wireless but Wired Connections are Working

Tags: router, wireless-router

Internet connectivity of all wireless connections is dropped simultaneously, with "yellow star" in the system tray icon of all machines but wired connections continue working fine without any problems whatsoever.

Then wireless connects automatically within a minute or so.

The router I'm using is: Linksys WRT120N
OS on all laptops(3-4) is Win7 and with 3 handhelds (ablackberry and 2 androids)

I have already tried switching the channel to a less crowded one, increasing lease-time to one day and adding DHCP reservations and now it seems a dead-end.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Can you see something relevant in router log? (I shure, You can see it in web interface

Comment: @mmv-ru - thanx for the quick reply, and no, i haven't checked the router logs yet. I will find them and let you know of the updates.

Comment: More, Your Wi-Fi is open or WPA protected with good pass? If it open, there can be other (fake) network with same SSID.

Comment: I cannot find the router log but Wi-Fi is WPA protected for sure, and the key is good too..as per my standards though!!

Comment: Sometimes it works fine for hours at a stretch, nd sometimes disconnects 5 times in an hour, its really irritating!
The devices re-connect automatically within a minute or two, but if i do it manually, "cannot connect" message appears and connection stabilizes with adapter reset after click "troubleshoot problems"..
Its getting really confusing, because i know for sure that the laptop is not the problem, router is!

Comment: What is status of wireless connection when problem arrive? It connected or not. It unclear from Your description.
Look at network/change properties of interfaces in Win7 and ipconfig /all in Win cmd.

Comment: @mmv-ru: I used the ipconfig/all in both connected & disconnected scenarios and saved the results but how do is share them with you?  I found the router log, but with only 4 categories(incoming,outgoing,security,DHCP clients) its not helpful   The status is 'connections available', status bar showing blank wireless signal with a yellow star icon.

Comment: You can save log on pastebin and publish link in question. MS site say yellow star mean disconnected from network (http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_7-networking/wireless-network-tray-icon-shows-yellow-star-even/70c6b8ee-6922-4fd2-a45a-a37013cad3f6)

Comment: @mmv-ru: Well that is the issue, all systems disconnect from wireless simultaneously, and reconnect again automatically!!

Comment: I only can think about some break connection. Like authentication attack, or pulse noises or conflict with other strong wireless signal (may be not 802.11). But it hard to diagnose and troubleshoot.

Comment: One more idea. Check You don't have in LAN some multicast traffic? Like IPTV, some ip surveillance camera etc...

Comment: @mmv-ru : Again, I have absolutely no idea how to check that!